# Case insensitive sort in django rest framework with mongoengine

Tags: django, mongodb, django-rest-framework, mongoengine

Django already has a way to achieve this for RDBMS:

```
MyModel.objects.order_by(Lower('myfield'))
```

I'm using DRF with [mongoengine](https://github.com/MongoEngine/mongoengine) but the above throws error:

```
TypeError: 'Lower' object is not subscriptable
```

I'm guessing this is a bug in the way order_by has been implemented in mongoengine.

Answer (score 0):

I actually think it might be a bug with Django, see:
https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/30557

Don't think that's made it to the 2.2 stable release yet but it's in the Django 3.0 release.